# Using Node.js module fluent-ffmpeg to convert video but my files end up corrupt

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-conversion, node-modules

i am writing a node based media encoding tool and have found a few good node packages that will help me to do this, but the output files are either totally corrupt or it only encodes half the video.

The main node package i am using is [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg), and i am trying it with the following code:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'uploads/robocop-tlr1_h480p.mov', nolog: false})
  .withVideoCodec('libx264')
  .withVideoBitrate(800)
  .withAudioCodec('libvo_aacenc')
  .withAudioBitrate('128k')
  .withAudioChannels(2)
  .toFormat('mp4')
  .saveToFile('output/robocop.mp4',
    function(retcode, error){
        console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
});
```

There is not a problem with the source video as i encoded it just fine using FFmpeg normally with the following comand line string (i run it from a batch file):

```
"c:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i %1 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -ac 2 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800k -f mp4 "../output/robocop2.mp4"
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Should it be .withVideoBitrate('800k') ?

Comment: I agree with @szatmary, 800 bps is probably the reason.

Comment: Hi there, i tried your suggestion - made no difference. Besides the github docs show it just as being: .withVideoBitrate(800). Thanks for the suggestion though.